# How to shorten imports in Android Studio for cleaner code

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there an easy shortcut in Android Studio to refactor this:

```
@GET(WSConstants.ENDPOINT_SINGLE_ACCOUNT)
suspend fun getAccount(@Path(WSConstants.PARAM_ACCOUNT_ID) accountId: String?): Call<Account>
```

to:

```
@GET(ENDPOINT_SINGLE_ACCOUNT)
suspend fun getAccount(@Path(PARAM_ACCOUNT_ID) accountId: String?): Call<Account>
```

And secondly, is it considered good practice? I think it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no straightforward solution to do what you want. So:

**Solution #1**

Click on the each field, for example `ENDPOINT_SINGLE_ACCOUNT`, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then press on the first option which is <kbd>Add import for ...</kbd>. It replaces all occurrences of the selected field with the desired notation in the current file.

---

**Solution #2**

The briefest way to do so is to use `wildcard imports` (`*`) while importing multiple fields. It'd be the highest level of contraction.

```
import your-package.*
```

To gain the benefit of this brevity, first, pull out your constants from the object class and put them into a kotlin file:

**WSConstants.kt**

```
package your-package

const val ENDPOINT_SINGLE_ACCOUNT = "..."
const val PARAM_ACCOUNT_ID = "..."
```

Then

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the `Replace in Path` window
2. Enable regex by pressing `.*` at the right of the window
3. Replace `WSConstants[.*]` with an empty string to remove `WSConstants.` patterns in the classes

replace `WSConstants`

[image]

---

**Additional:**

To define your own policy to organize imports, you can do it from:

> File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Kotlin > Imports (Tab)

Comment: I'm surprised that there is no straightforward solution because I think it makes the code definitely more readable and simpler. But thanks for this!

Comment: Thank you Jim :) Yeah, I've explored all the related IntelliJ docs to find a clue, unfortunately with no success. I agree with you, this way the code appears cleaner, At least due to removing unnecessary prefixes, the code fragmentation occurs less.

Answer (score 2):

When importing write full path of the static variables.
For example:

```
import my.package.name.WSConstants.ENDPOINT_SINGLE_ACCOUNT
import my.package.name.WSConstants.PARAM_ACCOUNT_ID
```

Comment: I want a shortcut. Writing full path is too much work

Comment: Import cann not be shortened. But after imoorting with full path you can use constants as you asked

Comment: There has to be some setting in Android Studio I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no import aliasing mechanism in Java. You cannot import two classes with the same name and use both of them unqualified.

Import one class and use the fully qualified name for the other one, i.e.

```
import com.text.Formatter;

private Formatter textFormatter;
private com.json.Formatter jsonFormatter;
```